# Azure Function X-FORWARDED-FOR Header format IPV6?

Tags: azure-functions, ipv6, ipv4, x-forwarded-for

What is the format of the `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header of an HTTP-triggered Azure Function, when client makes request from an IPV6 endpoint?

IPV4 headers come across as...

- `111.222.333.444:<port#>`

I'm imagining IPV6 headers come across as...

- `[2001:db8:85a3:8d3:1319:8a2e:370:7348]:443`

...but I need to know for sure (and don't have a simple way to test)

Comment: I'd really like to know the answer to this, too, but AFAICT we'll never see IPv6 addresses show up in `x-forwarded-for` unless Azure Front Door is in place: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/587342/doesnt-azure-web-application-support-ipv6 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/676236/ipv6-for-app-services

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if it has hexadecimal notation it should be IPV6. I am sharing some relevant links which might help you in this case:

https://phoenixnap.com/blog/ipv4-vs-ipv6

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/what-is-the-difference-between-ipv4-and-ipv6/dab02f67-1592-4b4f-ad3a-f830f22ec8fd

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-ipv4-and-ipv6/

You may try this as well : https://www.vultr.com/resources/ipv4-converter/?ip_address=fe80::fd9f:f2cc:a4b6:eea3